# Can I pass a presentational component a class based component as a property and have the presentational component render it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a presentational component that I want to render a class based component, but I do not want to import it into the presentational component, I want to pass it as a property. Is that possible? Is there a better way to do this?

Here is how I am rendering the presentational component in its container, it's name is TodaysRevenueThumbnail:

```
renderTodaysRevenueThumbnail() {

        if (!this.props.todaysTotalRevenue || !this.props.todaysSales) {
            return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
        } else {
            return (
                <TodaysRevenueThumbnail
                    totalRevenue={this.props.todaysTotalRevenue}
                    sales={this.props.todaysSales}
                    name={"Today's"}
                    ChartComponent={<TodaysRevenueChart/>}
                />
            );
        }
    }
```

You can see I am trying to pass it an instance of another component called TodaysRevenueChart.

Here is how I try to render TodaysRevenueChart inside of TodaysRevenueThumbnail:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const TodaysRevenueThumbnail = ({totalRevenue, sales, name, ChartComponent}) => {

  return (
    <div className="revenueThumbnail">
      <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12" >
        <div className="thumbnail">
          <ChartComponent todaysSales={sales} />
          <div className="caption">
            <h3>{name} Total Revenue: ${totalRevenue}</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodaysRevenueThumbnail;
```

I get an error in the console that says:

"invariant.js:38Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `TodaysRevenueThumbnail`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than passing a rendered *instance*, pass the component constructor:

```
<TodaysRevenueThumbnail
    totalRevenue={this.props.todaysTotalRevenue}
    sales={this.props.todaysSales}
    name={"Today's"}
    ChartComponent={TodaysRevenueChart}
/>
```

Comment: That solved the problem and worked exactly as I intended.

Answer (score 1):

Pass it as `ChartComponent={TodaysRevenueChart}` and it should work.

Understand that jsx like

```
<TodaysRevenueChart foo="bar" />
```

roughly transforms into

```
{ type: TodaysRevenueChart, props: { foo: 'bar' } }
```

That's the shape react expects to be returned from render, what it knows what to do with. In some sense, jsx is a convenient way to make it *seem* like you're executing your component when in reality you're passing along that responsibility to react.